# diaplying a specific number the result of a diference between 2 numbers minus a certain percentage

Tags: javascript

First i want to say i have  zero knowledge of js or any coding so i am just trying here.

I have a script that tells me, in console log, the simulated result of a battle between 2 opponents. But now the system has changed and  i receive points based on the HP left, after the battle ends, in increments of 10% of the hp lost. So if i have 100 hp and i lose 10,  90 hp gets me 25 points , 91 still 25 points ,  89 -24 points ...etc lower with each 10% lost.

So i have tried to write the code below (admitting idk if i wrote it correctly)

```
matchRating = playerHP - opponentHP;
 if (matchRating >= playerHP - 10%) {
    matchRating = '25';
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 20%) {
    matchRating = '24';
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 30%) {
    matchRating = '23';
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 40%) {
    matchRating = '22';
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 50%) {
    matchRating = '21';
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 60%) {
    matchRating = '20';
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 70%) {
    matchRating = '19'; 
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 80%) {
    matchRating = '18' ;
    }
else if (matchRating >= playerHP - 90%) {
    matchRating = '17';
    }
```

i get an Parsing error  unexpected token. and it doe not work

Comment: `First i want to say i have zero knowledge of js or any coding so i am just trying here`--> Why dont you learn the language before trying out the code? It will help you in the long  run. To answer your error, `80%` is not a valid number format.

Comment: This is a fairly fundamental misunderstanding of percentages of a number. To get 10% of a variable try `variable * 0.1`. 0.5 for 50% and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all, let's map HP to points:

```
`90-100` HP == `25` points
`80-90` HP == `24` points
`70-80` HP == `23` points
`60-70` HP == `22` points
`50-60` HP == `21` points
`40-50` HP == `20` points
`30-40` HP == `19` points
`20-30` HP == `18` points
`10-20` HP == `17` points
`0-10` HP == `16` points (but this you don't stated) ...
```

So result is that you start at `16` points and multiply it by `HP / 10` because 10 HP will icrease the points by 1

So the formula should be

```
var matchRating = playerHP - opponentHP;
var points = 16 + Math.floor(matchRating / 10)
```